# Django templates - can you pass arguments to template tags *args style?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I am trying to implement some breadcrumbs in my templates.

I some view urls take one argument and others two.

```
url(r'^firstpage/(?P<arg_one>(option1|option2))/(?P<unique_identidfier>[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890\-_]+)/', views.MyView.as_view(), name="two_arg_view"),

url(r'^secondpage/(?P<unique_identidfier>[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890\-_]+)/', views.MySecondView.as_view(), name="one_arg_view),
```

I would like to pass in an array of breadcrumbs to via get_context_data, then loop over them in the template:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
        {%for crumb in breadcrumbs %}
            <a href="{% url crumb.url arg1 optional_arg2 %}" >{{ crumb.text }}</a>&nbsp;>&nbsp;    
        {% endfor %}
        {{ current_page }}
</div>
```

Is there a way I can pass an optional number of arguments to the url template tag?

In the same way you might when calling something with *args?

What I want to do (but doesn't work) is:

```
 <a href="{% url crumb.url *crumb.args %}" >{{ crumb.text }}</a>&nbsp;>&nbsp;
```

Comment: You should be doing this in the view, and then passing the args as a context variable to your template. At that point, you can definitely loop over them.

Comment: What part should I be doing in the view? Generating the url text? It feels like I will end up putting display logic in the view if I go down that route.

Answer (score 1):

An [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) will most likely do what you're looking for.

Inclusion tags can accept the current template context and you can retrieve your view values from there instead of having to manually pass them in. By including a template that contains the div, anchor tag, etc, you keep your templates simple:

```
{% tag_url %}
```

instead of having to repeat a bunch of conditional statements and loops.

I wouldn't recommend doing this sort of logic in a view, as it's not encapsulated or re-usable.